# TemplateSyntaxError while including javascript code in template

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I am trying to follow this [site](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_form_steps.asp)  to create a multi step form in my django app, from this code

`{% render_field form.car_make class="form-control" placeholder=form.car_make.label oninput="this.className = ''" %}`

i am getting the following error

> TemplateSyntaxError at /newcar1/
> Could not parse the remainder: '"this.className = '' from '"this.className = ''

I tried escaping the js thus

`{% render_field form.car_make class="form-control" placeholder=form.car_make.label oninput="this.className = ''"|escapejs %}`

but still getting the same error.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: seems like quote miss match here `'"this.className = ''`.

Comment: I can't see any quote miss match `oninput="this.className = ''"`
oninput=[**Open double quote**]this.className = [**Open single quote**] [**close single quote**] [**close double quote**]